# Run two jenkins version on the same linux machine

Tags: linux, jenkins

I have Jenkins already running in my Linux machine on port 8080. This is my current Jenkins config:

```
 JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins
 JENKINS_WAR=/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
 RUN_STANDALONE=true
 HTTP_PORT=8080
```

This tutorial has been followed to install the above configuration: https://dev-admin-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Jenkins%20CI/Run_Jenkins_Under_Another_Username/

Now I would like to install second Jenkins version on the same machine and I want the Jenkins to be running on a different port for example 8081. I know that this is possible on the windows machine by passing parameters -DJENKINS_HOME and httpPort while starting Jenkins.

Is it possible to do something similar on a Linux machine? If so, please suggest the steps.

Comment: It should work exactly the same way on Linux as it does on Windows,

Comment: @RamanSailopal I usually start jenkins on my linux machine using the command 'sudo service jenkins start'. I am not sure how to do that if i have two copies of this configuratuion file.

Comment: Cooy the service file to another file i.e. jenkins1.service. Amend it and change the config parameters within the file. Run systemctl daemon-reload and then systemctl start jenkins1

Comment: @RamanSailopal one is the /etc/init.d/jenkins1 file and another/etc/default/jenkins1  as shown in this tutorial here https://dev-admin-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Jenkins%20CI/Run_Jenkins_Under_Another_Username/ ?